# How do I target the new string to a specific span?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the 'success' event from Clipboard.JS to change the button text after some one have click it to provide a feedback that the text is successfully copied.

There are multiple `span` inside the `button` element, the feedback/new string (Copied!) will replace the original text (Take Me There) and be applied to the first `span` when the function is invoked.

If the feedback/new string apply to the first `span`, then the original text (Take Me There) will not be replaced instead the feedback will be appear on top since it applied to the first `span`.

How do I make the new string to the `span` that include the original text(the last span)? Please try to run the code for clearer illustration.

Below is my code:

```js
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.copyElement')

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    let span = e.trigger.querySelector('span')
    let oldtext = span.textContent
    span.textContent = 'Copied!'
    setTimeout(() => span.textContent = oldtext, 2000)
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.Big {
  width: 257px;
  padding: 33px 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.RedPhotonEffect {
  color: rgba(239, 71, 111, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(239, 71, 111, 0.12);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.RedPhotonEffect span:nth-child(1){
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #ef476f);
  animation: animate1 3s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  0%{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.RedPhotonEffect span:nth-child(2){
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #ef476f);
  animation: animate2 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0%{
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}

.RedPhotonEffect span:nth-child(3){
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #000, #ef476f);
  animation: animate3 3s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes animate3 {
  0%{
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.RedPhotonEffect span:nth-child(4){
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000, #ef476f);
  animation: animate4 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate4 {
  0%{
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<button
  class="copyElement RedPhotonEffect Big"
  data-clipboard-text="123"
>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span>Take Me There</span>
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.8/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am confused on this question- `make the new string to the span that include the original text?`. Do you want to replace text from "Take me there" to "copied" ?

Comment: @Tethys0 Same question: Do you want to replace this <span>Take Me There</span> with something?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Ace: I think you need to better explain your problem, you have two - and now three - people all struggling to understand your question. "*a new string/text will [temporarily] replace the original text...*" - will replace what "original text"? "...[That] new string will be included in the first span instead of the last span which include the original text*" - so you want the "new string" (where does this "new string" come from?) to go into the last `<span>`? And then be moved after a "temporary" amount of time (how long?) into the first span? Should it stay there? What about the original text?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Sorry for the confusion and please refer to the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then try using a class instead

```js
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.copyElement')

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    let span = e.trigger.querySelector('.label')
    let oldtext = span.textContent
    span.textContent = 'Copied!'
    setTimeout(() => span.textContent = oldtext, 2000)
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.Big {
  width: 257px;
  padding: 33px 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.RedPhotonEffect {
  color: rgba(239, 71, 111, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(239, 71, 111, 0.12);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.RedPhotonEffect span:nth-child(1){
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #ef476f);
  animation: animate1 3s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  0%{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.RedPhotonEffect span:nth-child(2){
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #ef476f);
  animation: animate2 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0%{
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}

.RedPhotonEffect span:nth-child(3){
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #000, #ef476f);
  animation: animate3 3s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes animate3 {
  0%{
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.RedPhotonEffect span:nth-child(4){
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000, #ef476f);
  animation: animate4 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate4 {
  0%{
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<button
  class="copyElement RedPhotonEffect Big"
  data-clipboard-text="123"
>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="label">Take Me There</span>
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.8/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```